# Snowflake- How to ignore the row number (first column) in the result set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, series

Whenever i run any select query in snowflake the result set is having auto generated row number column (as a first column).. how to ignore this column from the code...

Like : select * from emp ignore row;

Comment: don't do a `select *` if you want only columns `a, b, c` ask for what you want, and then your compile times and execution times will be improved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the unnamed column just before TABLE_CATALOG in the below picture.

I'm pretty sure that's not something we can not change -> maybe if you wrote some custom JS to fiddle with the page you might be able to hide it by perhaps changing the TEXT color to white or something. But that seems like a lot of work.

If you extract the data to a CSV (or any file format) this number does not appear in the payload.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes am referring to the unnamed column available at the first position.. But this column and numbers are also exporting to python dataframe along with the actual first column of the table (as a single column)... not sure how to ignore this unnamed column in my dataframe code.

Answer (score 0):

When you query Snowflake, regardless of which client you use, that column won't be returned.

It is a pure UI thing in the Snowflake Editor for readability.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But this column and numbers are also exporting to python dataframe along with the actual first column of the table (as a single column)... not sure how to ignore this unnamed column in my dataframe code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening in python. then below could help. Also refer https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-cursor-to-fetch-values

```
result = cur.execute("select * from table")

#assign to a variable
result_var = result.fetchall()

#write into a file
result.fetch_pandas_all().to_csv(multiple_table_path, index=False, header=None, sep='|')
```